# Is it true that if $K/F$ is a splitting field and $\phi \colon K \to K'$ is an isomorphism fixing $F$ then $K = K'$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ and $K'$ be finite extensions over a field $F$ such that $K$ is a splitting field for a polynomial $p(x)$ over $F$, and let $\varphi \colon K \to K'$ be an isomorphism which fixes $F$.  Is it true that $K = K'$?

This is stated as a theorem in [Pinter](http://books.google.ca/books/about/A_Book_of_Abstract_Algebra.html?id=mgYSPwAACAAJ) but I am having some difficulty following the (sparse) proof.

The proof begins with the fact that any such isomorphism takes a root of a polynomial to some other root of the polynomial.  So, if $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ are the roots of $p(x)$ in $K$ then $\varphi(c_1),\ldots,\varphi(c_n)$ are the roots of $p(x)$ in $K'$.  But Pinter asserts that $\varphi$ *permutes* the roots, by which I assume he means that $\varphi(c_k) = c_j$ for some $j$ for each $k$.  But it's not clear to me why such a statement of equality would even make sense, since $\varphi(c_k) \in K'$ and $c_j \in K$.

I came across [this answer by Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14130/5531) which seems to hint at where some of my confusion is coming from.  It seems like I need to first assume that $K$ and $K'$ are embedded in another field $E$ before even using the symbol "$=$".  I would certainly appreciate some clarification on this point.  This is why I asked "Is it true?" in the title.

Then, if I understand correctly, we can use the fact that $K$ and $K'$ are simple extensions, say $K = F(a)$ and $K' = F(b)$, and embed them in $F(a,b)$.

I think the next step would be to extend $\varphi$ to an automorphism on $F(a,b)$.  Then, since the roots of $p(x)$ are already in $F(a,b)$ and $\varphi$ sends roots to roots, it must permute the roots.  But I don't see how to construct such an extension.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both the answer by Arturo and the answer by Keenan are excellent.  I wish I could accept both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely doesn't make sense to assert that $K=K^\prime$ unless you have already embedded them into some other extension of $F$. What you can say is the following: if $L$ is any extension of $F$ at all, and $i_1,i_2:K\rightarrow L$ are two $F$-monomorphisms of $K$ into $L$, then $i_1(K)=i_2(K)$ (the images are the same). This is because $K/F$ is normal. You can assume $p$ is irreducible over $F$. Let $j$ denote either of $i_1,i_2$. If $\alpha$ is a root of $p$ in $K$, then because $j$ is an $F$-monomorphism, $j(\alpha)$ is a root of $p$ in $L$. Let $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ be the distinct roots of $p$ in $K$. Then $K=F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, and it follows immediately that $j(K)=F(j(\alpha_1),\ldots,j(\alpha_n))$. Since $p$ splits over $K$, it also splits over $L$, and its distinct roots are the $j(\alpha_k)$. Now observe that none of this depended on $j$. This means that the sets $\{i_1(\alpha_1),\ldots,i_1(\alpha_n)\}$ and $\{i_2(\alpha_1),\ldots,i_2(\alpha_n)\}$ are the same. Thus the images $i_1(K)$ and $i_2(K)$ are the same (they are generated over $K$ by the same set of elements).

If we did not assume that $p$ splits in $K$, then this argument would fail. We know if $p$ splits that it has $n$ distinct roots, and it follows that $p$ has $n$ distinct roots in any extension of $F$ in which it splits. Since the elements $i_1(\alpha_1),\ldots,i_1(\alpha_n)$ are $n$ distinct roots of $p$, they give all the roots of $p$ in $L$. The same argument applies for $i_2$. We have two sets of $n$ distinct roots of $p$, and since $p$ has exactly $n$ distinct roots, these sets must be the same. If $p$ didn't split in $K$, say it only had one root, but it split in $L$ with $3$ distinct roots, then by sending the one root to different roots in $L$, we would get two embeddings with different images.

Comment: Do we have to assume that $j$ fixes $F$ to ensure that $\alpha$ is a root of $p$ $\Longrightarrow$ $j(\alpha)$ is a root of $p$ is true?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise all you could say is that for a root $\alpha$ of $p$, $j(\alpha)$ is a root of $j(p)$, where $j(p)$ means you apply $j$ to each of the coefficients of $p$ to get a polynomial in $L[X]$.

Comment: Thank you Keenan.  I really like this approach using inclusions, it makes the argument very clear.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 5):

It is not true that the fields must be "identical".

Consider the two splitting fields of $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{R}$, one given by the usual $\mathbb{C}$, and another one, $\mathbb{D}$, given by numbers of the form $a+bj$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $j^2=-1$. As sets, these two fields are not *equal*, though the two fields are certainly isomorphic over $\mathbb{R}$ (by mapping $a+bi\in\mathbb{C}$ to $a+bj\in\mathbb{D}$).

If both $K$ and $K'$ are contained in some field $E$, though, then the argument holds: remember that $p(x)$ has at most $\deg(p)$ roots in *any* integral domain that contains $F$; in particular, since the roots of $p(x)$ in $E$ are $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, and are also $\varphi(c_1),\ldots,\varphi(c_n)$, then the two sets of roots must be equal; i.e., $\varphi$ is a permutation of the roots that are in $E$.

The next step to remember is that part of the definition of "splitting field" is that $K$ is *generated* over $F$ by the roots; that is, $K = F(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$, and likewise $K'=F(\varphi(c_1),\ldots,\varphi(c_n))$. But if $\{c_1,\ldots,c_n\}=\{\varphi(c_1),\ldots,\varphi(c_n)\}$ as sets, then clearly we have
$$K = F(c_1,\ldots,c_n) = F(\varphi(c_1),\ldots,\varphi(c_n)) = K',$$
giving the desired equality. This is all taking place inside a bigger field $E$.

In *this* situation, with both $K$ and $K'$ contained in a field $E$, then we *do* get equality of $K$ and $K'$ as sets, and in particular $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $K$.

In general, though, you cannot do as you propose. Remember that $F(a,b)$ is only defined *contextually*. In general, given a field $F$, an extension $E$, and a subset $X$ of $E$, $F(X)$ means "the smallest subfield of $E$ that contains both $F$ and $X$." In order to speak about $F(a,b)$, you need to *already* have an overfield that contains $F$, contains $a$, and contains $b$; you cannot create it *ex nihilo* simply by saying "consider $F(a,b)$."

(We can get away with it when we adjoin a single element $\alpha$ for the following reason: there is a theorem that says that given a field $F$ and a polynomial $p$, there is an extension of $F$ that contains a root of $p(x)$. So given $\alpha$ that is to be algebraic, if $p(x)$ is the monic irreducible of $\alpha$, we can consider such an extension and let $F(\alpha)$ be the corresponding field *there*. Then we have another theorem that tells us any two ways of doing this will result in *isomorphic*, though not necessarily identical, fields. But there is no parallel result for two or more elements)

Again, consider the situation I give above with $F=\mathbb{R}$, $K=\mathbb{R}(i)$, $K'=\mathbb{R}(j)$. There is no field that contains both $K$ and $K'$ *as sets*; there is no "$\mathbb{R}(i,j)$" to consider. The assertion is false when you do not assume that both splitting fields are contained in the same field; *however*, you *can* prove that any two splitting fields of the same (set of) polynomial(s) over $F$ are *isomorphic* over $F$.

Comment: Thank you Arturo, I was indeed confused on the point about $F(a,b)$.

Comment: And I am apparently still confused.  Why could I not start with $K = F(a)$ and $K' = F(b)$ (as in the question), say that $b$ is algebraic over $F$ so that it is algebraic over $F(a)$, then construct $F(a)(b)$ in the method you mentioned in your parenthetical remark (e.g. by modding $F(a)[x]$ out by the ideal generated by the minimal polynomial of $b$)?  Would it not be right to refer to this as $F(a,b)$?

Comment: @Antonio: Try it with my example again: You first construct $\mathbb{R}[i]$. Then how do you construct $\mathbb{R}[i,j]$? Your original polynomial that defined $j$ need not be irreducible over $\mathbb{R}[i]$, so you cannot guarantee the construction does what you think it does: you don't get a copy of $\mathbb{R}[j]$ inside that extension, because the former assumes that $j$ is a root of an **irreducible**. If you try doing that construction with my examples, you are forced into $j=i$ or $j=-i$ (depending on which irreducible factor of $x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{R}[i]$ you pick).

Comment: @Antonio: In other words: you cannot do that construction and *guarantee* that $a$ an $b$ will remain the distinct objects that you had to begin with. There is a difference between using $a$ and $b$ as placeholder names for "some root of..." and using $a$ and $b$ to represent specific elements of some field. I cannot guarantee the existence of a field $\mathbb{R}(i,j)$ where $i\neq j$, $i\neq -j$ (which I had to begin with) and in which both $i$ and $j$ are roots of $x^2+1$. But I *can* guarantee the existence of some extension of $\mathbb{R}$ that has roots of $x^2+1$.

Comment: I had that example in mind while typing the comment.  Since the polynomial for $j$ splits over $\mathbb{R}(i)$, either choice you take, $j=i$ or $j=-i$ would give $\mathbb{R}(i,j) = \mathbb{R}(i)$.  I still do not see the problem.  Either $b$ has a nonlinear minimal polynomial over $F(a)$ and we could use the construction I mentioned or it has a linear one, by which $F(a)(b) = F(a) = F(a,b)$.

Comment: @Antonio: Again: it depends on whether your $a$ and $b$ are already objects that you have around, or if you are using these names as simple placeholders for roots of polynomials. In the example, $i$ and $j$ are *explicit*, *specific*, *distinct* objects, so we *cannot* have $j=i$ or $j=-i$; after all, the letter 'j' is not equal to the letter 'i'. These are elements of specific fields $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{D}$, and I cannot guarantee the existence of a field that contains the field $\mathbb{C}$ as a subset, and the field $\mathbb{D}$ as a subset, with $\mathbb{C}\cap\mathbb{D}=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Hmm.  I think I am starting to see.  Thanks for putting up with my thickness. :)

Comment: @Antonio: If I'm only using `i` and `j` as placeholder names for roots, then we can perform the construction "add a root, then add another root". But then we have no guarantee that the labels $i$ and $j$ will refer to different elements. In the situation you have, $K$ and $K'$ are already given and specified, you cannot redefine their elements to suit you; $a$ and $b$ are already specific elements in specific sets, you cannot simply talk about $F(a,b)$ because there may not be a field that contains both $F(a)$ (subset of $K$) and $F(b)$ (subset of $K'$).

Comment: @Antonio In the case that $a$ and $b$ are placeholders for arbitrary roots of irreducible polynomials $f$ and $g$ in $F[X]$, say, in which case the notation $F(a)$ (and similarly $F(b)$) has a meaning intrinsic to $F$, then there will always be an extension of $F$ containing both (take a maximal ideal of the tensor product $F(a)\otimes_FF(b)$ and mod out), but then when you form the composite in such a field, which you might call $F(a,b)$, that object is not well-defined in general. In general, it depends on how you embed the two fields.