# Minimal polynomial and field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I know that, in general, for field  extensions $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\beta)$ of a field $F$ with the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ equal to that of $\beta$, it is not necessarily true that $F(\alpha)=F(\beta)$.

Now I was wondering, are there certain extra conditions on $F$ for which this statement would hold?

More specifically, is this, for example, true if $F=\mathbb{Q}$ or does the statement depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: It may fail for $F=\mathbb{Q}$: take $p(x)=x^3-2$, $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$, and $\beta=\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$, where $\omega$ is a complex cubic root of unity (equivalently, a root of $x^2+x+1$). Then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ contains nonreal complex numbers.

Comment: Related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14103/can-two-different-roots-of-an-irreducible-polynomial-generate-the-same-extension) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69997/splitting-a-polynomial-with-one-root).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So the statement depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Or is there just not a specific set of condition for which the statement would hold?

Comment: I don’t think it’s a simple condition; some fields have it (finite fields); some polynomials have it; but it would be hard to set down conditions that are both necessary and sufficient, as the MathOverflow thread suggests.